# Fix a title in place and scroll the remaining content in a responsive div element

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` panel floating in the center of the page. The panel is responsive to shrink down in height when the browser window is resized vertically.

I am trying to keep the content within it scrollable, but leave the title fixed in place, so it doesn't scroll with it.

The difficulty I am having, is that the height of the main `div` element is responsive with a percentage, and so I can't get the top panel to stay fixed at a `px` height, whilst keeping the content panel responsive with it. In the example below, I'm close to achieving this, but fall short on resize as the scrollable content panel (`div2`) falls outside of `div1`.

I'm confident I am going about this in the wrong way, but this is the code I have tried so far:

```css
body {
    background-color: #000;
}

.title {
    position: fixed;
    height: 35px;
    width: 100%;
}

.div1 {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    width: 450px;
    height: 85%;
    top: 7.5%;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 25px -5px #3E3E3E;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 25px -5px #3E3E3E;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    position: absolute;
}

.div2 {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: absolute;
    height: 85%;
    top: 65px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>419studios BetaPortal</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="div1">
        <div class="title">
            <h2>Title</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="div2">
            <p>Test</p><input type="text" value="Hello">
            <hr>
            <p>Test</p><input type="text" value="Hello">
            <br>
            <p>Test</p><input type="text" value="Hello">
            <p>Test</p><input type="text" value="Hello">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Things *tend* to resize naturally. Consider simplifying with just 1 div above another. Make the top div `position: absolute; top: 0;` and I think you're pretty much done. Use overflow on the lower div, as you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you exactly want to do:

```css
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
    }
    body{
        background: #999999;
    }
    .wrap-outer {
        height: 50%;
        width: auto;
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
        position: absolute;
        top: 25%;
        padding: 0;
        margin-left: 50px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    }       
    .wrap-inner {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 300px;
    }

    .title {
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
    }
    .title h2{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        line-height: 40px;
    }

    .content {
        overflow-y: scroll;
        height: calc(100% - 60px); /* 40px of title height + 20px of border radius */
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>419studios BetaPortal</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrap-outer">
        <div class="wrap-inner">
            <div class="title">
                <h2>Title</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <p>Test</p><input type="text" value="Hello">
                <hr>
                <p>Test</p><input type="text" value="Hello">
                <br>
                <p>Test</p><input type="text" value="Hello">
                <p>Test</p><input type="text" value="Hello">
                <p>Test</p><input type="text" value="Hello">
                <hr>
                <p>Test</p><input type="text" value="Hello">
                <br>
                <p>Test</p><input type="text" value="Hello">
                <p>Test</p><input type="text" value="Hello">
                <p>Test</p><input type="text" value="Hello">
                <hr>
                <p>Test</p><input type="text" value="Hello">
                <br>
                <p>Test</p><input type="text" value="Hello">
                <p>Test</p><input type="text" value="Hello">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly it, thank you so much for your help @GeorgeDiril